# Iterative function in SQL, postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a gigantic script that I would like to create in an iterative way (while or for loop), so it becomes overviewable and much shorter. It makes so much sense that it should be doable in SQL but so far I have not succeeded. What I did now in order to make it work is a lot of selections that I UNION together to make one table.

I want to iterate through the years, so while year is lower then 2017 execute function with the year in it as variable, starting from 1995.

So actually, an iterative function that fills in all years in the following lines of code and combines all results within one table: I will keep trying myself and update the code if I make progress.

```
SELECT 
    regio, 1995 as year, sum("0") as "0", sum("1") as "1", sum("2") as "2", sum("3") as "3", sum("4") as "4", sum("5") as "5", sum("6") as "6", sum("7") as "7", sum("8") as "8", sum("9") as "9", sum("10") as "10"
FROM 
    source 
where
    year = 1995 OR "year-1" = 1995 OR "year-2" = 1995 OR "year-3" = 1995 OR "year-4" = 1995 
group by 
    regio
UNION
SELECT 
    regio, 1996 as year, sum("0") as "0", sum("1") as "1", sum("2") as "2", sum("3") as "3", sum("4") as "4", sum("5") as "5", sum("6") as "6", sum("7") as "7", sum("8") as "8", sum("9") as "9", sum("10") as "10"
FROM 
    source 
where 
    year = 1996 OR "year-1" = 1996 OR "year-2" = 1996 OR "year-3" = 1996  OR "year-4" = 1996 
group by 
    regio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT regio, g.yyyy as year, sum("0") as "0", sum("1") as "1",
       sum("2") as "2", sum("3") as "3", sum("4") as "4",
       sum("5") as "5", sum("6") as "6", sum("7") as "7",
       sum("8") as "8", sum("9") as "9", sum("10") as "10"
FROM source CROSS JOIN
     generate_series(1995, 2017) g(yyyy)
WHERE g.yyyy IN (year, "year-1", "year-2", "year-3", "year-4")
GROUP BY regio, g.yyyy;
```

Comment: man. You are a hero. That is perfect. I can't accept your answer for 8 minutes. You really saved me so much work man.